# Random or non random

Tags: statistics, random

If I have a function $F(x)$, and the range of answers $F$ can provide is $1, 2$ or $3,$ is the output produced by $F$ "random"?

The computer science professor's response: No, it is not random, because the output MUST be $1, 2$ or $3$ and cannot be anything else. It can never be $4,$ so it is not random because you have knowledge of what the output must be.

The math professor's response: Yes, it is random because even if you limit the range of possible answers, you don't know which answer it will be.

So the core question seems to be if something is "random" if you can restrict it down to certain possibilities?

Comment: What do you mean by 'is $F$ random?'

Comment: Should I repeat my question?

Comment: I don't know what your trying to ask.

Comment: It depends a bit on what you mean by random, but I would go with the math professor's response, unless of course $F$'s behavior is determined solely by its input and we just don't know how that dependence works.

Comment: @Ian, can you elaborate on "it depends ..." or link me something I can read to better answer your question.

Comment: The CS professor's response is incorrect. By his logic, rolling a die cannot be random because 7 is not a possible outcome. Whether the math professor is correct depends on the interpretation of what your function is doing. If it maps from a set of outcomes to a set of numbers, and there is a valid probability distribution defined on the set of outcomes, then $F$ is a random variable and the numbers it "produces" can be construed as random.

Comment: @Michael The point is that you could define "random" to mean whatever you want it to mean. Math is not the English police. But it's silly to require the meaning of "random" to require, say, all real numbers as possible values. If you did that, people would then routinely need to use some other word to get at "unpredictable except in that it is confined to some range".

Comment: This is ill defined.  If the function always returns $1$ then the assumptions are satisfied.  You need to tell us more.

Comment: @Michael your CS professor is right

Comment: [See here](https://engineering.mit.edu/engage/ask-an-engineer/can-a-computer-generate-a-truly-random-number/) Nothing is random in computer logic, the number is usually generated with actual coordinates which vary according to time/geographic parameters/user variants ...etc modulo something

Comment: @Idle001 Many modern CPUs have a [true random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator). See [Intel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand) for example. Whether these are genuinely random is probably unanswerable at a fundamental level (is it knowable whether anything in the universe is genuinely random?) but they're certainly not algorithmic/predictable like a conventional pseudorandom number generator.

Comment: @Bungo This takes the question to a philosophical level, because even a die falls according to impalpable factors, like wind, shape/curvature of the ground, initial speed, the might ..... etc

Comment: @Idle001 Yep, copper.hat's question pretty much sums it up: depends on what you mean by "random"

Comment: The answer to your "core" question has been thoroughly settled centuries ago.  A function can be random even if the possible outcomes are in a finite set, as with a truly random coin toss or roll of dice.  If the function is computed by a deterministic Turing machine then we call the function "pseudo-random."  If the computer employs a truly random co-processor (e.g., one based on the random decay of isotopes), then it is a "truly random number generator" or TRNG, even if the possible outcomes are from a finite set.

Comment: The claim that it's not random is (likely to be) strictly correct (since the outcome is not actually probabilistic, even if it could usefully be modelled that way -- but the reasoning given in your question is not. Ask the CS professor whether the outcome of die roll (whose faces are marked 1,2,3,1,2,3)is random -- if the reasoning you give is what the professor said, it seems the professor's answer would have to be "no". (it can't produce a "4" either!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without getting into a useless 'war' between math and CS, let me
try to sort out the usual terminology. At best, the question seems to be dealing
with *reports* of *informal* comments made by faculty members.

In **statistics and probability modeling**, it is certainly possible
to have a random sample from a small discrete population. Usually
that means that each population element has an equal chance of being
chosen and that choices are made independently. In your example
the population is $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and in rolling a fair die, as in @Bungo's
comment, the population is ${1,2,3,4,5,6}.$

Other random variables can produce (in theory at least) continuous values.
An example is the distribution $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1),$ which can take any
value on the real line, but concentrates about 95% of its output to the
interval $(-2,2).$ It is not possible to have a random variable that
puts equal probability on each of the real numbers. [In practical applications,
one must round the continuous values to some number of decimal places, so
that results become 'discrete' rational numbers, and tied values may occasionally occur.]

In **computer simulation,** most models are built on numbers that are
(or are essentially indistinguishable from) realizations of a random
variable $U$ with the distribution $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1).$ 
Traditionally, computer applications have used deterministic algorithms (e.g.,
the 'Mersenne Twister')
that are carefully chosen to produce values that cannot be
distinguished from a random sample from $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$ using
many different statistical tests of randomness (see Marsaglia's 'Die Hard' battery of tests). These are called 'pseudo-random' values; if not truly random they are relentlessly unpredictable.  More recently, as in @Bungo's link to Intel, some processors have tapped 'high-entropy pools' to
obtain numbers from sources thought, on the basis of physical theories, to
be truly random. Perhaps quantum computing will provide new sources
of random numbers.

Everything else is built up from random values $U \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,1)$. For example a random variable from $\mathsf{Exp}(1)$ with density function
$f(x) = e^{-x},$ for $x > 0,$ can be generated as $X = -\log_e(U)$.
Even discrete random variables are generated from uniform ones: for example
$Y \sim \mathsf{Binom}(1, .5)$ can be generated by taking $Y = 0$ if $U < .5,$ and $Y = 1,$
otherwise.

So it is easy to see how a CS professor could insist that
the source of all computer generated random models is a distribution that
is uniform on $(0,1)$ (but not uniform on all real numbers). In fact, however,
digital computers do arithmetic on an extremely large subset of the rational
numbers--not on all real numbers, not even on all real numbers in $(0,1).$

---

Here is how one could simulate 6000 tosses of a fair die using R statistical
software. The function `sample` is based on pseudorandom numbers indistinguishable from $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1).$ The argument `rep=T` indicates
that sampling is done 'with replacement'. The output consists of approximately
equal frequencies for each of the faces 1 through 6--nearly enough equal
that they pass a 'goodness-of-fit' test. (Of course, if all six counts were
*exactly* 1000, one would be suspicious that randomness is not being properly simulated.) The plot shows simulated results; red dots atop bars are at the theoretical probabilities $1/6$ for each face of the die.

```
x = sample(1:6, 6000, rep=T)
table(x)
##  x
##    1    2    3    4    5    6 
##  999  983 1003  983 1016 1016
```

[image]

Comment: Are there any sensible generators of U(0,1) alea that are not ultimately based on / using generators of {0,1} (binary) alea?